# How in Linux bash how to check if script file exist and execute it in one liner

Tags: linux, bash

I have many scripts in different directories , 
i want to check if those script file exist and then execute them in one liner in shortest way .
there is the simple way :

```
if [ -f /A/B/C/foo.sh ]; then /A/B/C/foo.sh
```

can i shorten this one liner ?

Comment: Why do you want it shorter?, the one you have is clear and as expected

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
/A/B/C/foo.sh
```

The [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) will check if this script file exists and then execute it. If the script does not exist, it will report

```
bash: /A/B/C/foo.sh: No such file or directory
```

Alternatively, you can suppress the error message with

```sh
/A/B/C/foo.sh 2> /dev/null
```

As others suggested, you can also check the script existence on your own using

```sh
[ -x /A/B/C/foo.sh ] && /A/B/C/foo.sh
```

Note the `-x` instead of `-f` (tests if the file is executable).

If you have many scripts in different directories, you can execute them using the following one-liner:

```sh
for f in /A/B/C/foo.sh /D/E/F/bar.sh; do [ -x "$f" ] && "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this:

```
run() { [[ -x $1 ]] && "$@"; }
```

And then use function as:

```
run '/A/B/C/foo.sh'
run '/A/B/C/bar.sh'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ -f /A/B/C/foo.sh ] && /A/B/C/foo.sh
```

The `&&` is a C-like `and`. If the command on the left return true, execute the command on the right.

Comment: i don't want the second /A/B/C/foo.sh

Comment: It's a basic command. If you find a special command for that problem, it's in the basically the same probably.

Answer (score 0):

Try bash [test command](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html):

And how it's works.

```
$ cat src.sh
echo "Test test"

//if src.sh exist
$test -e src.sh && sh src.sh
Test test

// if not, src.sh not run
$test -e src1.sh && sh src.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can be further shortened with shorthand format:

```
[ -f /A/B/C/foo.sh ] && /A/B/C/foo.sh || echo "script not found"
```

Comment: Be careful with using `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3` instead of `if ... else ...`. Check out [Bash Pitfall #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3).